# Shiny leaflet display point weight based on zoom level breaks down when using if-else statement

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a basic shiny app with a leaflet map.The circles should stay as they are until a user zooms to zoom-level 8, at which point the weight should be 2. When the zoom becomes 9 or higher, the weight should become 3.

Here is my attempt. The app breaks down when I go to zoom level 9 with `Error in resolveFormula: Unexpected two-sided formula: (input$map_zoom > 8) ~ 3`

```
## app.R ##
library(leaflet)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "500px")
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  df <- data.frame("Lat"=c(32.921821,32.910853,32.793803,32.995084,32.683745,32.759999,32.800652,32.958861,32.835963,32.762578,32.649651,32.862843,32.862217,32.936876,32.963381),
                   "Long"=c(-96.840609,-96.738831,-96.689232,-96.857858,-96.825345,-96.684475,-96.794144,-96.816111,-96.676371,-96.897331,-96.944426,-96.754719,-96.856976,-96.752718,-96.770249))
  
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$map_zoom, {
      print(input$map_zoom)           # Display zoom level in the console
      leafletProxy(
        mapId = "map", 
        session = session
      )%>% 
        addCircles(data=df,lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, weight = if(input$map_zoom <=8) ~2
                   else(input$map_zoom >8) ~3,
                   opacity = 1, fill = TRUE, fillOpacity = 1 )
    }
  )
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles(urlTemplate = "//{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/jcheng.map-5ebohr46/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
               attribution = 'Maps by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>') %>%
      setView(lng = -96.84, lat = 32.92, zoom = 6) 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `case_when` as

```
weight = case_when(input$map_zoom <=8 ~2, input$map_zoom >8 ~3)
```

This works fine for me:

```
observeEvent(eventExpr = input$mymap_zoom, {
      print(input$mymap_zoom)           # Display zoom level in the console
      mywt <- case_when(input$mymap_zoom <=8 ~1, input$mymap_zoom >8 ~6)
      print(mywt)
      leafletProxy(
        mapId = "mymap" , session = session
      )%>%
        clearShapes() %>% 
        addCircles(data=df,lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat,
                   weight = mywt ,
                   opacity = 1, fill = TRUE, fillOpacity = 1 )
    }
  )
```

You just need  `clearShapes()`

Comment: I think that's almost it. Your code covers the case where the user zooms in, but the circles don't adjust back to their original size when you zoom back out to the original zoom. Weird because you're code looks like it should handle that.